# ERROR [HY000] ERROR: Aggregate function calls may not be nested */

Tags: sql, netezza, aginity

I cannot get the below line to work when adding to my query, any thoughts?
**stddev(stat) bias**

```
with c as (
    SELECT A.ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE, A.LEVEL_1_CODE CURR, CNTR_TO_ACTIVE_RISK, A.PRICE, a.ACTIVE_WEIGHT_PCT,
           lag(a.PRICE, 1) over(partition by a.LEVEL_1_CODE order by a.ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE) price_lag,

           lag(CNTR_TO_ACTIVE_RISK, 1) over(partition by a.LEVEL_1_CODE order by a.ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE) risk_lag,

           price_lag/a.PRICE - 1 rtn,
           a.ACTIVE_WEIGHT_PCT * rtn wgt_rtn
    FROM DBS_APPL_RISK_DATAMART.USR_OWNR_RISK_DATAMART.VWC_FOREIGNEXCHANGE_FUND_EXPOSURE A
    WHERE A.PORTFOLIO_CODE = 'Sunsuper Active - SUKHH3_Active'
)

SELECT c.*,
       sum(wgt_rtn) over(partition by c.ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE)sum_rtn,
       sum(risk_lag) over(partition by c.ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE)sum_risk_lag,
       sum_risk_lag/sqrt(260) over(partition by c.ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE)sum_lag_risk2,
       sum_rtn/nullif(sum_lag_risk2,0) stat,
       stddev(stat) bias


FROM c

order by c.ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using column aliases in expressions in the same select where they are defined.  You are also mixing aggregation functions in a `select` that has no `group by`.

Perhaps this will fix your problem:

```
WITH . . .
SELECT c.*, sum_rtn / nullif(sum_lag_risk2, 0) as stat,
       stddev(sum_rtn / nullif(sum_lag_risk2, 0)) over () as bias
FROM (SELECT c.*,
             sum(wgt_rtn) over (partition by c.ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE) as sum_rtn,
             sum(risk_lag) over (partition by c.ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE) as sum_risk_lag,
             sum_risk_lag/sqrt(260) over (partition by c.ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE) as sum_lag_risk2
      FROM c
     ) c
ORDER BY c.ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE desc
```

I'm not sure what the standard deviation should be partitioned by.  This is over all the data.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this works when partitioned over c.ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE.

Comment: Is there a way to have the standard deviation figure (bias) as a 30 day lag?

Comment: @TimCooper . . . I would suggest that you ask another question.  Try to simplify the query a bit, if you are only focused on `bias`.